# Pyspark array preserving order

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a structure along these lines, an invoice table and an invoice lines table.  I want to output the lines as a JSON ordered array in a mandated schema, ordered by line number but the line number isn't in the schema (it is assumed to be implicit in the array).  As I understand it, both pyspark and json will preserve the array order once created.  Please see the rough example below.  How can I make sure the invoice lines preserve the line number order. I could do it using list comprehension but this means dropping out of spark which I think would be inefficient.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct

invColumns = StructType([
    StructField("invoiceNo",StringType(),True),
    StructField("invoiceStuff",StringType(),True) 
  ])
invData = [("1", "stuff"), ("2", "other stuff"), ("3", "more stuff")]

invLines = StructType([
    StructField("lineNo",IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("invoiceNo",StringType(),True),
    StructField("detail",StringType(),True),
    StructField("quantity",IntegerType(),True)
  ])

lineData = [(1,"1","item stuff",3),(2,"1","new item stuff",2),(3,"1","old item stuff",5),(1,"2","item stuff",3),(1,"3","item stuff",3),(2,"3","more item stuff",7)]

invoice_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=invData,schema=invColumns)
#in reality read from a spark table


invLine_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=lineData,schema=invLines)
#in reality read from a spark table

invoicesTemp_df = (invoice_df.select('invoiceNo',
                                     'invoiceStuff')
                             .join(invLine_df.select('lineNo',
                                                     'InvoiceNo',
                                                     'detail', 
                                                     'quantity'
                                                     ),
                                                      on='invoiceNo'))

invoicesOut_df = (invoicesTemp_df.withColumn('invoiceLines',struct('detail','quantity'))
                                .groupBy('invoiceNo','invoiceStuff').agg(collect_list('invoiceLines').alias('invoiceLines'))
                                .select('invoiceNo',
                                        'invoiceStuff',
                                        'invoiceLines'
                                                    ))

display(invoicesOut_df)


3 -- more stuff  -- array -- 0: -- {"detail": "item stuff", "quantity": 3}
                          -- 1: -- {"detail": "more item stuff", "quantity": 7}
1 -- stuff       -- array -- 0: -- {"detail": "new item stuff", "quantity": 2}
                          -- 1: -- {"detail": "old item stuff", "quantity": 5}
                          -- 2: -- {"detail": "item stuff", "quantity": 3}
2 -- other stuff -- array -- 0: -- {"detail": "item stuff", "quantity": 3}
```

The following, as requested is input data

```
Invoice Table
"InvoiceNo", "InvoiceStuff",
"1","stuff",
"2","other stuff",
"3","more stuff"

Invoice Lines Table
"LineNo","InvoiceNo","Detail","Quantity",
1,"1","item stuff",3,
2,"1","new item stuff",2,
3,"1","old item stuff",5,
1,"2","item stuff",3,
1,"3","item stuff",3,
2,"3","more item stuff",7
```

and an output should look like this, but the arrays should be ordered by the line number from the invoice lines table, even though it isn't in the output.

```
Output
"1","stuff","[{"detail": "item stuff", "quantity": 3},{"detail": "new item stuff", "quantity": 2},{"detail": "old item stuff", "quantity": 5}]",
"2","other stuff","[{"detail": "item stuff", "quantity": 3}]"
"3","more stuff","[{"detail": "item stuff", "quantity": 3},{"detail": "more item stuff", "quantity": 7}]"
```

Comment: I think I should be using array_sort but I can't see how to use it.

Comment: Please include your input dataset and expected output in textual and structured format.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my block showed how the input and output should work,  I have added some simple text data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) does **not** respect data's order

> Note The function is non-deterministic because the order of collected results depends on the order of the rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

One possible way to do that is applying `collect_list` with a window function where you can control the order.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(invoice_df
    .join(invLine_df, on='invoiceNo')
    .withColumn('invoiceLines', F.struct('lineNo', 'detail','quantity'))
    .withColumn('a', F.collect_list('invoiceLines').over(W.partitionBy('invoiceNo').orderBy('lineNo')))
    .groupBy('invoiceNo')
    .agg(F.max('a').alias('invoiceLines'))
    .show(10, False)
)

+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|invoiceNo|invoiceLines                                                        |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1        |[{1, item stuff, 3}, {2, new item stuff, 2}, {3, old item stuff, 5}]|
|2        |[{1, item stuff, 3}]                                                |
|3        |[{1, item stuff, 3}, {2, more item stuff, 7}]                       |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```